# Re-rendering NextJS route (React component)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page (file name is `/home`) that looks like this:

```
class Index extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
               <Navbar />
               <Banner />
               <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

And in the `Navbar` component, i have:

```
<Link activeClassName="active" href="/home">
```

`Link` is the following component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { Children } from 'react';

const ActiveLink = ({ router, children, ...props }) => {
    const child = Children.only(children);

    let className = child.props.className || '';
    if (router.pathname === props.href && props.activeClassName) {
        className = `${className} ${props.activeClassName}`.trim();
    }

    delete props.activeClassName;

    return <Link {...props}>{React.cloneElement(child, { className })}</Link>;
};

export default withRouter(ActiveLink);
```

When i click on it, the components in the `/home` route do not re-render.
How can i force the re-render?